magick -append does not work
The following works:
convert -append *.jpg out.jpg

But, the following does not work:
magick -append *.jpg out.jpg

# Or:
magick -append file_1.jpg file_2.jpg out.jpg

Even though I'm told to use magick -append instead.
So, what should I do? Using convert -append *.jpg out.jpg until it's no longer working in future ImageMagick versions, then accepting that I will no longer be able to append images because magick command no longer permits it?

New v7 usage is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61208844/2836621

The input files are supposed to be listed before the -append operator:
This works fine for me (in the latest version, 7.1.1-36):
magick file_1.jpg file_2.jpg -append out.jpg

(It's true that in the older ImageMagick version 6, with the convert command, the order didn't matter.)
